# Show boolean values bootstrap table checkbox column from mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

I have mysql table as:

```
CREATE TABLE bd_grid.tbl_datatable (
`id`         int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name`       varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`email`      varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`mobile`     varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',
`start_date` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`status`     TINYINT(1),
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));
```

THE 'STATUS' COLUMN IS TO INSERT BOOLEAN VALUES (0,1), here's one example how I insert the boolean values.

```
INSERT INTO bd_grid.tbl_datatable(`name`,`email`,`mobile`,`status`) VALUES('Ricardo Alejandro Lopez Reyes','lopezr853@gmail.com','8443853097',true);
```

all of those values, I use bootstrap table to show them but the way that I want show the values from the column 'STATUS' is a checkbox column. If the value of 'STATUS ' is 0 the checkbox is unchecked, if the value of status is 1, the checkbox is checked.

```javascript
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var $table = $('#table');

                $table.bootstrapTable({
                    url:'list-user.php',
                    search:true,
                    pagination: true,
                    buttonsClass: 'primary',
                    showFooter: true,
                    minimumCountColumns: 2,

                    columns: [{
                        field: 'id',
                        title: '#',
                        sortable: true
                    },{
                        field: 'name',
                        title: 'Nombre',
                        sortable: true
                    },{
                        field: 'email',
                        title: 'E-mail',
                        sortable: true
                    },{
                        field: 'mobile',
                        title: 'Celular',
                        sortable: true
                    },{
                        field: 'start_date',
                        title: 'Fecha Inicio',
                        sortable: true
                    },{
                        field: 'status',
                        title: 'Estatus',
                        checkbox: true,
                        checkboxEnabled: true
                    }]
                });
        </script>
        </BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I load my bootstrap table all the checkboxes are unchecked, i use this file to iterate  all the data from mysql table

Please check the **list-user.php** code below. I am using this code to load information into BOOTSRAP table. The conditional `if ($rowList['status'] == 1)`, I want to change the status of my checkbox to unchecked but I really don't know how to manipulate the 'Status' column to change the checkbox.

**list-user.php**

```php
<?php
require 'db.php';

$sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tbl_datatable ")or die(mysqli_error($con));
$arrVal = array();

$i=1;
while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

    $name = array(
        'id' => $i,
        'name'=> $rowList['name'],
        'email'=> $rowList['email'],
        'mobile'=> $rowList['mobile'],
        'start_date'=> $rowList['start_date'],
        'status'=> $rowList['status']


    );

    if ($rowList['status'] == 1) {


        // CODE TO CHANGE THE STATUS OF THE CHECKBOX TO checked

        array_push($arrVal, $name);
        $i++;
    }

    else {

        // CODE TO CHANGE THE STATUS OF THE CHECKBOX TO unchecked
        array_push($arrVal, $name);
        $i++;
    }

}
echo  json_encode($arrVal);


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your columns:

```
columns: [{
   field: 'id',
   title: '#',
   sortable: true
},{
   ...
},{
   field: 'check',
   title: 'Estatus',
   checkbox: true
},{
   field: 'status',
   visible: false
}]
```

After the data table is loaded:

```
$table.on('load-success.bs.table', function() {
    $table.bootstrapTable("checkBy", {
        field: "status", 
        values: [1]
    });
});
```

If column status has value = 1 then the corresponding checkbox (from column check) is checked.
The documentation for checkBy method:

> Check a row by array of values, the params contains:
>
> > field: name of the field used to find records
> >
> > values: array of values for rows to check
>
> Example:  $("#table").bootstrapTable("checkBy", {field:"field_name", values:["value1","value2","value3"]})